# Changing EditText height and width on Runtime with some animation

Tags: android, listadapter

I have Four EditText with different background.
It looks like this:
[image]

I want to cover full screen when a EditText is selected with That EditText. For that I need to change the EditText width and height with some animation on Runtime.

When selected It should look like this:
[image]

How can I change EditText size with animation on Runtime ?

Comment: so , you need to use animation to make the edittext occupy layout's fill parent when request focussed on it. right?

Comment: @Raman yes.I've tried with your ans, But it wasn't that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it can be done with `Animations`. In android view takes all space before animation finished, so you will see that other editTexts disappears and selected one slowly increasing. Here is rough example how to do it without standart animations, but changing weights in separate thread:

layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et00"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:text="00" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:text="01" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:text="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:text="11" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in code add actions on changing focus:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    OnFocusChangeListener focusListener = new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
                EditText forDecresing = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    if (parent.getChildAt(i) != v) {
                        forDecresing = (EditText) parent.getChildAt(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                LinearLayout pp = (LinearLayout) parent.getParent();
                LinearLayout layoutForDecreasing = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < pp.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    if (pp.getChildAt(i) != parent && pp.getChildAt(i) instanceof LinearLayout) {
                        layoutForDecreasing = (LinearLayout) pp.getChildAt(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                startAnimation((EditText) v, forDecresing, layoutForDecreasing, parent);
            } else {
            }
        }
    };

    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et00)).setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et01)).setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et11)).setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et10)).setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    setWeight(findViewById(R.id.et00), 1);
    setWeight(findViewById(R.id.et01), 1);
    setWeight(findViewById(R.id.et11), 1);
    setWeight(findViewById(R.id.et10), 1);
    setWeight(findViewById(R.id.ll1), 1);
    setWeight(findViewById(R.id.ll0), 1);
}

Thread animationThread;

private void startAnimation(final EditText forIncreasing, final EditText forDecresing, final LinearLayout layoutForDecreasing,
        final LinearLayout layoutForIncreasing) {
    if (animationThread != null)
        animationThread.interrupt();
    animationThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int iterations = 0;
            int maxIterations = 30;
            setWeight(forIncreasing, maxIterations - 1);
            setWeight(layoutForIncreasing, maxIterations - 1);
            setWeight(forDecresing, maxIterations - 1);
            setWeight(layoutForDecreasing, maxIterations - 1);
            while (iterations < maxIterations) {
                iterations++;
                setWeight(forIncreasing, maxIterations - 1 + iterations);
                setWeight(layoutForIncreasing, maxIterations - 1 + iterations);
                setWeight(forDecresing, maxIterations - 1 - iterations);
                setWeight(layoutForDecreasing, maxIterations - 1 - iterations);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            animationThread = null;
        }
    });
    animationThread.start();
}

private void setWeight(final View view, final float weight) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            params.weight = weight;
            view.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });
}
```

I do not know if this is possible for you, but in this example you can add some more movements quite easy.

I do ***not*** recommend use it production, if only you have some other options.

Answer (score 6):

> ANSWER UPDATED :

use this code in drawable/animation_sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%" android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="500" />
```

And set the animation to the edit text using :

```
Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this, R.anim.righttoleft);
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width=display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
editText.setWidth(width);
editText.setHeight(height);

editText.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to explain my Logic for your problem...i hope so it would work for you..

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);  
editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

    public void onClick(){    
        // Before getSize was introduced (in API level 13), you could use
        // the getWidth and getHeight methods that are now deprecated:

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();   
        int width = display.getWidth();  
        int height = display.getHeight();  

        editText.setWidth(width);  
        editText.setHeight(height);
    }  
}
```

Comment: This was what i knew my dear friend...i am sorry i could help you furture....but still....you try with this concept for Animation...this is the right way to change the size at runtime and would also be helpful to change the size of animation...